# Property 'self.menuViewController' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller

I'm running into this error on a viewController and not sure why it's happening. The controller is currently set up like this:

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

  init(sideMenu: UIViewController, center: UIViewController) {
    menuViewController = sideMenu
    centerViewController = center
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)// This is where the error happens
  }

}
```

Any clue why this may be happening?

Comment: Can you add error message?

Comment: The error is ''Property 'self.menuViewController' not initialized at super.init call''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is happening in the second initializer because, well, the property isn't initialized.  All of your properties that aren't optional and don't have default values have to be initialized separately in each initializer, because only that particular initializer actually runs (unless it explicitly calls a different one).

If you're using the `coder` initializer, you'll need to assign it a value in there or make it an optional.  If you aren't actually implementing that initializer, leave it with the `fatalError` default, since if that ever runs it means something went horribly wrong anyway.

Comment: I see, that makes sense